# Caliburn.Micro: Active or Passive ViewModels for Dialogs?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, caliburn.micro

In general, which approach would be preferable for ViewModel initialisation?

### Active

An instance of the view model class is initialised, which then performs any data gathering of it's own (populating lists destined for drop-downs etc).

### Passive

An instance of the view model class is initialised, but the caller also then populates properties of the viewmodel object (lists destined for drop-downs etc).

I think I'd prefer the first approach as it seems those "dialog" view models would be more usable, but in situations where the calling viewmodel already has some of that data it might be beneficial to pass it in.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'd prefer the `Active` approach, I suppose you could go the hybrid approach.

Since most VM properties will be public (for binding) you can pass any values you have into the dialog VM from the calling VM by assigning via property setters.

When the dialog activates (I assume it will have lifecycle since it's a dialog) you can then check to see if any properties haven't been set, and load in what's missing.

Of course I would probably just go down the 'Active' approach - most dialogs don't need to load a ton of data but your mileage may vary.